# SELECT all orders data including matched and unmatched orders SQL

Tags: sql, join

I need to select all orders data including orders which lead to a transaction + those which didn't lead to a transaction.

Knowing that:

```
SELECT * FROM Buy_Orders
```

```
OrderID   OrderQuantity   OrderPrice      OrderPlacementDate   
-----------------------------------------------------------------
12        11              103             2021-10-12 14:02:22.703
14        6               100             2021-10-12 14:04:24.700
14        0               100             2021-10-12 14:07:27.206
17        3               80              2021-10-12 14:08:22.703
12        0               103             2021-10-12 14:09:21.501
20        20              23              2021-10-12 14:11:23.705
```

```
SELECT * FROM Sell_Orders
```

```
OrderID   OrderQuantity   OrderPrice   OrderPlacementDate   
--------------------------------------------------------------
9         2               13           2021-10-12 14:05:25.705
23        7               100          2021-10-12 14:07:27.205
23        1               100          2021-10-12 14:07:27.206
33        9               90           2021-10-12 14:08:28.403
90        1               103          2021-10-12 14:09:21.500
90        0               103          2021-10-12 14:09:21.501
```

```
SELECT * FROM Transactions
```

```
TransactionID    TransactionQuantity    TransactionPrice    SellOrderID    BuyOrderID       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
113              6                      100                  23             14     
123              1                      103                  90             12
```

Logic for TransactionID 113 ( SellOrderID 23 + BuyOrderID 14 ): transaction created when order 23 entered the order book at 2021-10-12 14:07:27.205 and matched order 14 (partial fill). That's why there was an update on both impacted orders (23 & 14) at 2021-10-12 14:07:27.206 in tables Sell_Orders and Buy_Orders. So, the match with quantity=6 will create an update on order 23 to re-enter the orderbook with quantity=1 and an update on order 14 to re-enter the order book with quantity=0 at 2021-10-12 14:07:27.206.

I have tried  the following SQL query but with no chance. I assume I'm not fluent with SQL. Please help!

```
SELECT 
    o.OrderID
    o.OrderQuantity
    o.OrderPlacementDate
    t.TransactionID 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
from 
       Sell_Orders 
UNION 
SELECT *
from 
      Buy_Orders ) o
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      TransactioID 
    FROM 
      Transactions ) t on t.SellOrderID = o.OrderID or t.BuyOrderID = o.OrderID
```

I expect to have this table as an output:

```
OrderID   TransactionID   OrderQuantity   OrderPrice   OrderPlacementDate
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
12        NULL            1               103          2021-10-12 14:02:22.703  
14        NULL            6               100          2021-10-12 14:04:24.700
9         NULL            2               13           2021-10-12 14:05:25.705
23        NULL            7               100          2021-10-12 14:07:27.205 -----> 1st Transaction
23        113             1               100          2021-10-12 14:07:27.206
14        113             0               100          2021-10-12 14:07:27.206
17        NULL            3               80           2021-10-12 14:08:22.703  
33        NULL            9               90           2021-10-12 14:08:28.403
90        NULL            1               103          2021-10-12 14:09:21.500 -----> 2nd Transaction
90        123             0               103          2021-10-12 14:09:21.501
12        123             0               103          2021-10-12 14:09:21.501
20        NULL            20              23           2021-10-12 14:11:23.705
```

Comment: What is the output you get?

Comment: Surely all orders with `order_id in (23,14,90,12)` should show a transaction_id? So that would be 8 rows, not 4?

Comment: Note: your query won't run as is, and debugging is a LOT easier when you actually shown the error messages that occur.

Comment: It seems, you compare **OrderPlacementDate** in JOIN conditions. For transaction (113            , 23, 14) you take rows(23,113, 1 2021-10-12 14:07:27.205)<-> (14 ,113, 0, 2021-10-12 14:07:27.205) and ignore(?) row (14, NULL, 6, 2021-10-12 14:04:24.700) with different DateTime

Comment: @Jens sorry to not adding the output that I've got it's because I've a got a very weird result showing deplicatons on the TransactionID (I've got almost 12 rows with the same ID) and my data structure is too big to add in the post. I just explained the logic here.

Comment: @MatBailie it should exactly be 4 rows. 2 for the orders in input and 2 for the updated orders when there's a transaction. Also, I didn't get an error. I had an output but with a lot of duplications and it doesn't fit the logic.

Comment: @ValNik it's not ignore. There will be an update on order 14 so it will re-enter the order book at 14:07:27.205 (when there was a transaction impacting the order)

Comment: Your transaction table says that TransactionID 113 is composed of SellOrderID 23 and BuyOrderID 13.  There are two rows in SellOrder with OrderID = 23 *(with the same value for OrderPlacementDate)*, and two rows in BuyOrder with OrderID 13 *(with different values for OrderPlacementDate)*.  That's ***four*** rows just for that single transaction.  What logic do you assert should be applied to pick just one SellOrder and one BuyOrder for that single Transaction?

Comment: I think, to join order list (Sale_order union all Buy_orders) with Transactions, need take only last (by time) enter (re-enter) order to Order book. By example ranking order entries **row_number()over(partition OrderId order by OrderPlacementDate desc) as OrderEntryRnk**, add to JOIN  ... **and OrderEntryRnk=1**

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks for your comment, I know it's a bit a confusing. I explain the logic:  TransactionID 113 ( SellOrderID 23 + BuyOrderID 14 ) was created when order 23 entered the order book at 2021-10-12 14:07:27.205 and matched order 14 (partial fill). That's why there was an update on both impacted orders (23 & 14) at 2021-10-12 14:07:27.205 in tables Sell_Orders and Buy_Orders. So, the match with quantity=6 will create an update on order 23 to re-enter the orderbook with quantity=1 and an update on order 14 to re-enter the order book with quantity=0 at 2021-10-12 14:07:27.205.

Comment: This means that you want Transaction 113 to associate with SellOrder 23 OrderQuantity 1 but not the row with OrderQuantity 7? BUT there is no way in your data to determine that the town with OrderQuantity 1 is an update to the town with OrderQuantity 7 (as the have the exact same timestamp). If you want to associate with ***just one*** SellOrder row, your data ***must*** have values that allow us to determine which is later / has highest precedence. *(Note; data sets in SQL are explicitly Unordered Sets, there is no Before or After except where it can be determined by applying an ORDER BY.)*

Comment: @ValNik SellOrder 23 has two rows with ***the exact same timestamp***, there is no apparent (to me) sensible (and deterministic) way to accurately rank/order those two rows.

Comment: @MatBailie Transaction 113 is to associate with SellOrder 23 OrderQuantity 7: to take 6 and leave 1 ( as it matches with BuyOrder 14 OrderQuantity 6).  The timestamp is not a big matter as my db is already having the orders flow in the exact time rank. I've edited my post with the price factor to understand the transaction logic - I'm sorry I didn't know you'll need all these details to understand the logic (finance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last subquery doesn't include the order id's, so there's nothing to join `t` on. Just don't use a subquery.

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      TransactioID 
    FROM 
      Transactions ) t on t.SellOrderID = o.OrderID or t.BuyOrderID = o.OrderID
```

Becomes...

```
LEFT JOIN 
  Transactions   t
    ON t.SellOrderID = o.OrderID
    OR t.BuyOrderID  = o.OrderID
```

***EDIT:***

You also want each transaction to join on just one buy order, and one sell order, which requires adding a ranking id to each order.

Provided that `(OrderID, OrderPlacementDate)` is ***guaranteed*** to be ***unique***, that can be accomplished with...

```
SELECT 
    o.*,
    t.TransactionID 
FROM
(
    SELECT
        *,
        'Sell' AS OrderType,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY OrderPlacementDate DESC)  AS OrderIDRank
    FROM
        Sell_Orders

    UNION ALL  -- ALWAYS use ALL unless you KNOW a reason otherwise

    SELECT
        *,
        'Buy' AS OrderType,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY OrderPlacementDate DESC)  AS OrderIDRank
    FROM
        Buy_Orders
)
    AS o
LEFT JOIN
    Transactions   AS t
       ON  o.OrderIDRank = 1
       AND o.OrderID    IN (t.BuyOrderID, t.SellOrderID)
```

Comment: Well done, thanks! Except ```ON  1          =  t.OrderIDRank``` should be ```ON  1          =  o.OrderIDRank``` ;)

Answer (score 1):

This query gets expected table

```
with All_Orders as( 
SELECT *,'S' as side from  Sell_Orders 
UNION ALL
SELECT *,'B' as side from Buy_Orders 
)
SELECT 
    o.OrderID
   ,case when TransactionQuantity<=OrderQuantity then null
          else TransactionId
     end TransactionId
   ,o.OrderQuantity
   ,o.OrderPlacementDate
    -- for info
   ,t.TransactionID as realTranId
   ,o.Side,TransactionQuantity
FROM All_Orders o LEFT JOIN Transactions  t on t.SellOrderID = o.OrderID or t.BuyOrderID = o.OrderID
order by OrderPlacementDate
```

Source row
12,        **11**,              103,             2021-10-12 14:02:22.703
may be ?
12,        **1**,              103,             2021-10-12 14:02:22.703

[DBFiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/GMLlveiv)